# Singular transformations

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Definition: A linear transformation is said to be singular if it's nullspace contains atleast one non zero vector.

I read another definition of a closely related topic which included matrices which is as follows:
A matrix is said to be singular if it's determinant is 0.

I tried relating the two. In my opinion, it means if there is one non zero vector in the nullspace then it means,  there has to be one less number of vectors in the basis of the range space. So when we calculate the row space, one row of the matrix has to be all zeroes, which also  makes the determinant 0. Is this right?

Comment: No. The rows/columns only need to be linearly dependent to have determinant  equals 0. Consider [1 1; 1 1].

Comment: But you are right that it is nessesary to have $\dim(T(V)) < \dim(V)$ since we have $\dim(T(V))+\dim(ker(V))=\dim(V)$

Answer (score 3):

$\det(A)=0 \iff $ $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$  $\iff Ax=0$ for some $x \ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:V\to V$ be linear, $\dim V = n$, and $M$ be it's matrix in some basis. If it's singular there is a nonzero vector in $\ker f$, so $\dim\ker f >0$, and since $\dim\ker f+\dim\textrm{im}\, f = n$ we have $\dim\textrm{im}\, f < n$. From the definition of matrix of transformation image of $f$ is spanned by columns of matrix $M$, and because $\dim\textrm{im}\, f < n$ columns of $M$ are linearly dependent, and therefore $\det M = 0$.